# Why is MySQL 8.0 AES_ENCODE unsafe for statement-based replication?

Tags: encryption, aes, mysql

I read this interesting note in the [MySQL 8.0 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) that seemed a bit confusing to me:

> Statements that use AES_ENCRYPT() or AES_DECRYPT() are unsafe for statement-based replication.

As I understand it, that means that AES_ENCRYPT will not generate the same result given the same parameters across two different machines. Is there something inherent about the AES algorithm that would cause the function to produce different results across two machines? Particularly, it seems to me that AES_DECRYPT should be required to produce the same result given the same parameters. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to decrypt the original message.

Comment: I know this is a 3 year old post, but in case anyone comes here from google [this answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65256634/1152524) explains it: long story short, just make sure your [`block_encryption_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_block_encryption_mode) is the same on your replicated servers.